# Is an efficient C++ conditional spinlock possible?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a situation in multi-threaded C++ code where I need to make some very fast operations atomic (appear serialised) so I can use a spinlock such as:

```
lock mutex: while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
unlock mutex: lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);
```

However I thought to be clever, and make the locking conditional on whether the data structure is currently shared by more than one thread or not:

```
lock mutex: if(lockneeded) while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
unlock mutex: if(lockneeded)lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);
```

Initially, the data structure is owned by only one thread but access can be granted to another thread *by the owner* at which point it has to set the lock-needed variable (which has to be an atomic bool itself).

Will this work?

---

EDIT: some context. I have a system which schedules coroutines. A queue of suspended coroutines is run one at a time by a single thread until it suspends or completes, then the next one is run. This system was originally designed for a single thread, since coroutines by specification are sequential programming constructs. The context switching time is extremely fast because coroutines use heap allocated linked lists for stacks, not the machine stack. So a context switch is basically just a pointer swap.

Then I decided to optionally allow more than one thread to process the list, so the coroutines become processes. Now the pointer swaps must be done atomically. The swaps are extremely fast, so a spinlock seems like the right way to guard the operations.

I have a test case, where I run a set of jobs serially, then do it again with extra helper threads. I had a problem which i have now fixed that turned out to be unrelated to scheduling. Now, 4 threads run the process about 3.5 times faster than 1.

The performance objective is simple: I want to wipe Go-lang off the face of the planet. My system is C/C++ ABI compliant (Go isn't), it uses the correct model for stream processing (Go doesn't), and its a hands down vastly superior language as well.

I don't know how fast Go can context switch. But the current untuned version of my test case, in which we must not forget jobs count to 100K to create a delay (and ensure near zero contention on the lock), is processing 2 MILLION processes in 5 seconds, which is a context switching rate of about 400K switches per second. I expect if I replace the slow jobs with null jobs (do nothing coroutines), the rate will exceed 1 milllion switches per second. That's running 2 million processes. The real world speed will be lower, the experiment is trying to find the upper bound on performance.

Comment: Format the post properly and provide a [mcve] if you want to ask about a specific scenario. It is of particular importance when dealing with multithreading to have a *complete* example.

Comment: Given that the `bool` need to be atomic, I am not sure if it could ever increase performance as you are adding an extra instruction. Have you measured the performance of the 3 cases (no lock, lock and lock + bool) in the single thread case to see the actual impact? If not, maybe, it is premature optimization?

Comment: So you reached the point where the right thing to do is to make lockneeded a counter of the threads that have access... so that the spinlock should be implemented in term of this counter... => this is almost a mutex!

Comment: @Phil1970: no, i haven't measured performance yet, I'm asking if it will work. The current code uses a mutex. The concurrent version on a late model Mac is 10 times slower than the single threaded version. It uses the equivalent of the conditional lock. In that case the costs of the condition test is small compared to the cost of using the mutex. I plan to replace the mutex with a spinlock. After that i may try without the conditional. The application is actually a user space scheduler.

Comment: @Oliv: no its not a count, its either 1 thread or more. Plan at present is that it does not revert even if one of the threads goes away. So it starts at false, and can go to true once, in a single thread before the second thread starts and that's the end of it. That's enough I think. At least it will do at the moment, there are more critical issues to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any race condition with the new approach. Is `lockneeded` only modified by the **single** thread?

Comment: `spinlock` would only be efficient if the wait is minimal (a few clock cycles). Otherwise, you will waste CPU cycles and reduce battery life. Spin lock and mutex are intended for different use cases. It seems suspicious that sometime you need a lock, sometime not. If the code with a mutex is 10 time slower, then maybe data you only be processed by a single thread and eventually made available to other threads only when done. Lock-free structures might also be useful...

Comment: @Phil1970 yes, the lockneeded variable is set once, by the sole thread which can access it, before it spawns another thread which can also access the data structure. The choice of whether to use extra threads is up to the user not me. I don't know why the mutex is causing a problem, because the concurrency causes a problem even with very long job lengths. The code being protected by the lock is extremely short and very fast. And the performance issue persists with the spinlock. Don't understand yet. Different code with long jobs performs OK.

Comment: @Phil1970: the "application" is a user space scheduler. Its not a particular thing, its a general purpose thing. So the choice of threading or not is not mine, i just have to make the scheduler as fast as possible *if* the client choses to use concurrency. In fact, it is part of Run Time Library of my programming language and the upgrade *should* mean it outperforms Go-lang.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately this will not work.

Say Thread A sees `lockneeded` is false and enters the critical section without acquiring `lock`, then a context switch occurs in the middle of the critical section. Thread B requests access to the data structure. The data structure doesn't know Thread A is in the critical section, so Thread B is granted access. `lockneeded` is set to true, but Thread A is already inside its critical section. Thread B then acquires `lock`... you can easily see that this is undefined behavior.

It can't work unless you can guarantee that `lockneeded` won't change during the critical section. A way to guarantee that `lockneeded` won't change is to use a lock to protected it. So you would need to add a lock to every access of `lockneeded`, therefore defeating the purpose of the variable in the first place.

Efficient C++ spinlocks

A spinlock is so conceptually simple, yet there are many flavors available. The important factors to consider are performance requirements (does it *really* need to be that efficient?), architecture, threading library, desired scalability, amount of expected contention (if contention is rare, you can optimize for the non-contention case), asymmetry of critical sections using the same lock (to prevent thread starving), ratio of reading to writing... You can see that if you need it to be super efficient, there's a lot of performance testing you need to do. So if you don't really need the performance, you should just use the spinlock you have and spend your time elsewhere.

But we're computer scientists and we like the most efficient solution because we're problem solvers. For a highly contentious, highly scalable spinlock, check out MCS lock. For a generally good spinlock, I ran some tests a while ago and found that pthreads' spinlock was pretty scalable.

And there is another way to guarantee that Thread A is not in the critical section without Thread A having to write anything. It's called rcu_synchronize and, to grossly oversimplify, it would involve Thread B setting `lockneeded` and waiting a sufficient amount of time to guarantee that any thread in a critical section will finish it.

The naive spinlock is scales poorly because of the bus traffic due to cache misses of the lock variable (a global write invalidates other cores who are also spinning).

A simple optimization you can do is the "spin on read" spinlock:

```
lock mutex:   while (lock.load(std::memory_order_acquire) || lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {}
unlock mutex: no change
```

So if another thread has the lock, this thread doesn't bother with the TSL (due to OR short-circuiting), but when the other thread releases the lock, the thread attempts the TSL which may or may not be successful. Unfortunately, this lock performs as poorly as the naive spinlock in high-scaling scenarios but might save you a some cycles from time to time over the naive spinlock in a low-scaling, medium-contention situation.

Comment: I think you missed some critical information. Lockneeded is initially false, and there is only one thread. That thread sets lockneeded to true before it spawns the second thread. So the scenario you describe cannot happen. The only issue here is that the spawned thread must see the value of lockneeded is true, which it is prior to the second thread being spawned. In my systems the spawning machinery uses a mutex to force the spawner to wait until the spawnee tells it that it has actually started running, and that should be sufficient memory ordering.

Comment: So, you are correct, that performance testing is required. But the first step for me is to get something half-way reasonable also clearly and unambiguously correct. That way some test cases can be set up and measured, and tuning attempts can be compared for both performance and correctness. The short-circuit read-first optimisation you show is definitely one to consider.

Comment: So FYI at the moment on OSX, the concurrent version of the test code is 10 times SLOWER than the single threaded version. On Linux, its better, only 13 seconds. There is close to zero contention, there are 200 jobs which loop incrementing a counter a lot of times. The results for 100,000 jobs that do nothing is similar. So the lock is highly efficient. It seems caching and scheduling issues are the killer. I need more experiments.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you spawn a new thread every time you need to do a job? Spawning a thread to handle a job is like hiring a clerk to check out one customer. The initial cost to spawn a thread can easily outweigh the cost of doing the operation. Have you considered a threadpool?

Comment: The system starts with one thread running jobs from a queue. It is actually a synchronous coroutine scheduler, no concurrency. The current design allows one of the coroutines, whilst running, to spawn a new pthread as a helper. At present that choice is made by the author of the coroutine not the system. Once the new pthread starts, it shares the job queue with the scheduler that was running the coroutine that spawned it. The coroutines are then elevated (logically) to the status of processes.

Comment: FYI I found a problem that was slowing the test case down. My test now makes each coroutine count to 100K and exit. I generate 2G coroutines. The elapsed time for 1 thread for processing the already queued jobs is 20 seconds, with around 4 threads its 5 seconds. There are some quirks (the garbage collector runs once in the serial test) and the time counting to 100K is not known yet but should be enough to ensure close to zero lock contention. The context switching rate is in excess of 400K per second. I guess this will utterly and completely kill Go but I don't know. Its not even tuned yet.